# Rails get status from all checkboxes via jquery and send it to controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

So far I have the following setup:

My Checkboxes are declared like this:

```
<label id="cb2" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
     <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Meal</span>
</label>
```

And I have the following JQuery Code:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
       $("#change_me").html("<%= j render(partial: 'dynamic_test') %>");
     });
   });
</script>
```

So as soon as I check or uncheck a checkbox I want to get the check attribute of all checkboxes and send them to my controller(ajax?), where I then want to execute some select queries and render it in "dynamic_test". Could someone give me an idea on how to implement the data sending to my controller.

Edit:

My _dynamic_test.html.erb contains:

```
Some Test!
<%= @check_box_val %>
```

Edit2:

I got it to work like this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
   var selected_checkbox_val = [];
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if ( this.checked ) {
            selected_checkbox_val.push(this.getAttribute("name"));
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: "/meals/dynamic_test",
      type: "POST",
      data: { 
        value: selected_checkbox_val
      },
      dataType: 'script'  
    });
   });
 });
</script>
```

If you see a better way, I'm open for changes.

Comment: To which controllers action do you want to send them?

Comment: To "meals_controller#dynamic_test",  because that's what I want to display afterwards with "render partial".

Comment: Ok. I got an answer for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it

```
<script>
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var selected_checkbox_val = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/meals/dynamic_test",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
      value: selected_checkbox_val
    },
    dataType: 'script'  
  });
}
</script>
```

In the controllers `dynamic_test` method

```
def dynamic_test
  @check_box_val = params[:value]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

And you should have a file called `dynamic_test.js.erb` with the following code

```
$("#change_me").html("<%= j render(partial: 'dynamic_test', locals: {check_box_val: @check_box_val}) %>");
```

Also you should defind a route for this method

```
post "/meals/dynamic_test" => "meals#dynamic_test"
```

*Note:*

You can change the *name of the partial* to avoid confusion between *main template* and *partial template*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't figure out the @check_box_val. It's only content is "on" but I need to know which checkbox is having what value.

Comment: @Maxung What does your `dynamic_test` partial contains? Please share it in the question

Comment: Do I have to iterate through all checkboxes on my page, write them into an array and then send it via ajax?

Comment: @Maxung Yes! That could make things easier as we can track the checkbox by its index.

Comment: So it's giving me the following output currently with 3 checkboxes. "Some Test! ["on", "on", "on"]" even though only the last checkbox is checked. I think it has to do something .val() but I can't find another function.

Comment: @Maxung How are your other check boxes look like? Please share the code in the question